# calculate balance on certain day from monthly projection

Tags: bash, calculator

I have a list of my monthly outgoings that looks something like this:

1st - Car - 100

3rd - Rent - 400

7th - Gas and electricity - 51

8th - Phone - 12

17th - Internet - 30.74

21st - Insurance - 45.21

27th - Patreon - 2

28th - Water - 12.9

The above is an example but is similar in structure to my monthly outgoings.

Let's say I get paid on 23rd of every month. Could I write a script (preferably in bash) where I could input my current bank balance and it would subtract everything that's coming out of my bank between $CURRENT_DATE and the 22nd of the month?

So I could run this script any time in the month and get a quick glance at how much surplus money I have.

Comment: bash is normally the wrong choice if using decimal numbers (although you can use bc).  If the list is not actual dates but simply the numbers at the start, then I see no real problems in most languages.  awk could probably handle this quite well.  Show what you have tried and where you are stuck and someone is sure to help.  Also, you have shown the input, it would be nice to see the required output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an annotated bash solution, probably not the most optimal solution:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then
    echo "Missing argument: current balance"
    exit 2
fi

# current balance comes in as the first argument, multiplied by 100 for the cent-value (bc for decimal)
current_balance=$(scale=0; echo "${1} * 100" | bc -l)
# current day without leading zero
current_day=$(date +"%-d")
# the last day of the current month
last_day_of_month=$(date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" +"%d")
# the default target date is the 22.
target_day=22
offset=0

# if we're past the cut-off point, then we'll check until the 22. of next month
if (( ${current_day} > 22 )); then
    target_day=$(( ${last_day_of_month} + 22 ))
    offset=$(( $last_day_of_month ))
fi

# set the outgoings to be on the index of their date as their cent-values
outgoings=()
outgoings[1]=10000
outgoings[3]=40000
outgoings[7]=5100
outgoings[8]=1200
outgoings[17]=3074
outgoings[21]=4521
outgoings[27]=200
outgoings[28]=1290

# iterate over the days until we hit the target
for (( i=${current_day}; i < ${target_day}; i += 1 )); do
    # decrement by the offset (either by 0 or the amount of days in month)
    if (( $i > ${offset} )); then 
        index=$(( $i - $offset ))
    else
        index=$(( $i ))
    fi
    # if no outgoings for this day, continue
    if [[ -z "${outgoings[index]}" ]]; then continue; fi
    # calculate the current balance after this days outgoings
    current_balance=$(( $current_balance - ${outgoings[index]} ))
done

# divide the current left over balance by 100 to get the euro/dollar/whatever amount
left_over=$(echo "scale=2; ${current_balance} / 100" | bc -l)

echo "Extra money: ${left_over}"
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I'm selecting this one as my answer. It might not be the most optimal, but I was struggling to comprehend how to iterate through the days before/after payday and this script explains how to do just that! Cheers!

Comment: For the note, I didn't try this out, I just wrote it, so there's probably some errors in there.

Comment: I actually just read the script again, and found a major bug which I then promptly fixed. Please note the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

PAYDAY=$2
B=$1

sed '/^$/d; s#\([0-9][0-9]*\)st#\1#g; s#\([0-9][0-9]*\)nd#\1#g; s#\([0-9][0-9]*\)th#\1#g; s#\([0-9][0-9]*\)rd#\1#g' | while read line
do 
   lday=$(echo $line | awk -F'-' '{print $1}')
   amount=$(echo $line | awk -F'-' '{print $3}')
   if [[ $lday -gt `date '+%d'` && $lday -lt $PAYDAY ]]; then
      B=`echo "$B - $amount" | bc`
      echo $B
   fi
done | tail -1
```

If the balance is 1000

```
 cat list.txt | ./calc.sh 1000 23
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete awk solution would be:

```
awk -v sal="1000" -v datnow=$(date +%d) -v dat=23 -F\- '{ dat=dat--;if ( $0 != "" && +$1 >= datnow && +$i <= dat ) { vals[+$1]=+$3 } } END { for ( i in vals ) { sal=sal-vals[i] } print sal  }' balances
```

Where balances is the file with the data.

We pass the salary as sal (example 1000) and then pass pay day as dat. We also pass the current date as datnow.

We reduce the salary day by one check that the line is not blank, check that the day in the file is greater or equal to now and less than or equal to the pay day. If this is the case, an array is created and this array is finally looped through subtracting the values from salary to attain the remaining balance.